# How to run the IBM quantum lab without simulators?

Tags: qiskit

Seeing the announcements in the IBM lab simulator that it's going to be shut down soon. What's the workflow going to be without the cloud resources? Is there a free tier for the real qubit system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a major breaking change and will require workloads to use the Qiskit Local Runtime option. You can do this via the fake backends option, or via the Qiskit Aer simulators. The Aer option lets you simulate Clifford circuits, so is worth exploring even if you prefer the lower complexity of the fake backends.

See the docs here: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/local-simulators